# TryParsing from an object list to int | c#

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to take objects out of an object list to an int list. If the object list's value contains a string than I want to convert it to an int. the error that I'm getting is "cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan'. I've tried looking up examples and information about lists made of objects but couldn't find anything.

I'm also at a loss as to what to do with the 'else' part of the code.

```
public class ListFilterer
{
   public static IEnumerable(int) GetIntegersFromList(List(object) listOfItems)
   {

      List<int> Integers = new List<int>();

      foreach (var value in listOfItems)
      {
        int number = 0;

        bool success = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);

        if (success)
        {
          Integers.Add(number);
        }
        else
        {
          Integers.Add(number);
        }
      }
      return Integers;

   }
}
```

Comment: don't use parse it will give you error, get type of object if its int then parse it otherwise ignore it

Comment: so what do you suggest I use instead then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll probably work out if you TryParse `value.ToString()` instead, if you're looking for anything that might look like an int and can be converted to an int. If you only want things that actually are  ints, something like `if(value is int number)` should work if your c# version is recent. If it's older you may have to `if(value is int)` and then cast the value inside the if

Your code can be simplified to:

```
foreach(...){

  int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out var n);
  integers.Add(n);

}
```

Or

foreach(...){

```
  if(value is int)
    integers.Add((int)value);
  else 
    integers.Add(0);
}
```

Comment: No probs. I added a bit more advice too

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use:

```
var ints = listOfItems
  .Select(o => { int.TryParse(o.ToString(), out int num); return num;} )
  .ToList();
```

This will work as you wish, as if conversion fails `num` is 0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

If Try Parse fails number is automatically 0 so you can directly write this

```
 Int32.TryParse(value, out int number)
 Integers.Add(number);
```

Comment: yep! thank you this and the comment above in combination made the code work! thank you!

Comment: `value` is `object`, not `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find the better way

```
var intList = objs.ConvertAll(delegate (object obj) { return (int)obj; });
```

Comment: where objs is the list of objects